# Code First Migration ignore DatabaseGeneratedOption?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I tried to change a field into a computed field.

That is, from:

```
        Property(c=>c.IsPaid)
            .IsRequired();
```

into:

```
        Property(c=>c.IsPaid)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
            .IsRequired();
```

Then after add migration:

```
Add-Migration IsPaidAsComputed
```

Scaffolding migration gave me a migration class:

```
public partial class IsPaidAsComputed : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Citations", "IsPaid", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Citations", "IsPaid", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }
}
```

Is Entity Framework not smart enough to detect what our intentioned change is?

What is the correct way to `AlterColumn` into a computed field?